# Visual studio busy waiting for internal operation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Many times when hitting a break point during debugging my (WinForms) application, Visual Studio becomes unresponsive for 10-20 seconds, and I get the following message in the bottom right corner **Visual studio is busy: Microsoft Visual studio is waiting for internal operation to complete.** Every time it happens, I see that Visual Studio Standard Collector is using a lot of CPU. Can anybody tell me what this Standard Collector is, and if there is something to do to avoid this happening? This is on Windows 10, VS Community 2015 Update 1.

Comment: You may have to upgrade Visual Studio. See [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630071/visual-studio-standard-collector-unbounded-memory-usage) on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: VS is already updated

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1630071/visual-studio-standard-collector-unbounded-memory-usage

> **Posted by Allen [MSFT] on 11/3/2015 at 10:20 AM**:
>   Thank you very much for reporting this. We have researched the root cause and have made a fix that will be provided in VS2015 Update 1. Update 1 is due out in coming weeks.

Until you update, Allen suggests the following fix:

> Meanwhile, if you notice that hte process consumes too much memory you have two ways to recover. Simplest is just to restart your machine. That will get everything back to a fresh state. The other thing you can do to alleviate the memory consumption is to stop the Visual Studio Standard Collector Service using the Service Manager UI.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd1d1c57-fbf0-4076-a708-5e9516f359b1/visual-studio-standard-collector-service-disabled-for-productivity-during-debugging?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Well, Update 1 is out, so we don't have to cross our fingers and wait.

Comment: You're right, but some people are weirdly averse to updating, so I gave him an alternative too.

Comment: This service also goes wild on VS 2015 Update 2.